# Stop ipython pop-up docs

Tags: ipython

In the ipython qtconsole it automatically displays the documentation for a function when I type the opening parenthesis. For example, when I'm typing

```
plt.show()
```

the documentation for pyplot.show is displayed when I've typed

```
plt.show(
```

This documentation is displayed in a pop-up window that, much more often than not, blocks my view what I'm typing. Is there a configuration to stop the ipython qtconsole from doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The feature to which you refer is calltips or more precisely IPythonWidget.enable_calltips and is documented at https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/options/qtconsole.html. The only effective way I have found to disable it is by adding    --IPythonWidget.enable_calltips=False  as an argument to qtconsole that in turn an argument of ipython. A command line for all of this is:

```
ipython qtconsole --IPythonWidget.enable_calltips=False
```

I have verified this with IPython QTConsole 3.2.0 and believe it generally works for versions below 4, which I have not been able to install yet without breaking QTConsole. (I believe what some refer to as IPython 4 is also known as Jupyter 4. See below for information on Jupyter and disabling calltips in it.)

On Linux and Windows system, generating this command line can be automated using a bash alias. On Windows it can be automated by using it as the Target of an icon configured in its properties.

It is supposed to be possible to disable calltips by setting c.IPythonWidget.enable_calltips = False in the right configuraton file in which c = get_config() is set on the first line. I tried doing this on a Windows 7 system in ipython_qtconsole_config.py and ipython_config.py in ~.ipython\profile_default\ and several other locations, but could not get it to work.

Project Jupyter is the successor to the IPython project and began in 2014. Its website is http://jupyter.org and information about its Qt console is at http://jupyter.org/qtconsole/stable/index.html. In response to a question about disabling IPython calltips, which I submitted to https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues, I received the following on how to disable calltips for Jupyter:

On the command line

```
jupyter qtconsole --JupyterWidget.enable_calltips=False
```

or add

```
c.JupyterWidget.enable_calltips = False
```

to

```
~/.jupyter/juptyer_qtconsole_config.py
```